# Read newly arrived email c# using imap

Tags: c#

I want to read a newly arrived email c# using IMAP. Currently I am using the pop3client STAT Command to read the email and it is reading both inbox and sent box emails. In IMAP, it is possible to read only inbox emails but i want to read only newly arrived email not all emails of inbox.

Answer (score 1):

Use Limilabs framework for read mail. Its provide to read mail by various category.

See this [link](https://www.limilabs.com/blog/receive-unseen-emails-using-imap) . I hope it will help you

Answer (score 0):

> newly arrived email

Define that. If it is *"all mails received since I previously checked for newly arrived mail"*, then you need to mark mails as *"Seen"* when you scan the mailbox.

Answer (score 0):

You must have a looping function the check your mailbox within a certain period

while (true)
{
check mail.....

if (newmail) 
process...

thread.sleep(10000); sleep for 10 second

}

Comment: remember pop3 will automatically delete your email as soon as you have downloaded them, unlike IMAP/MAPI